# Where can you get by walking half a mile?

Tags: visualization, geography, geographics

I recently saw that Mathematica 10 introduced really nice tools for geography. I would like to use `GeoGraphics` to visualize all possible paths with a length of half a mile starting at a given location. This should show me were I could get within a half-a-mile walk.

For the starting point I selected `GeoPosition[{45.521,11.021}]` and I already plotted a map. I used `GeoRange -> Quantity[0.5, "Miles"` to cover up all possible paths. This leads me to:

```
GeoGraphics[
   GeoMarker[GeoPosition[{45.521, 11.021}]], 
   GeoRange -> Quantity[0.5, "Miles"]
]
```

[image]

How can I complete the plot?

Comment: You might find this post on the community interesting: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/942484

Comment: Im looking for the traveling distance.